# pylint does not work in emacs

Tags: python, emacs, pylint, syntax-checking

I have emacs24 (installed by homebrew), flycheck (installed by MELPA) and pylint (installed by pip) on my mac, and I have the following code

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'global-flycheck-mode)
```

in my .emacs file. However there's still no syntax checking when I type a python script. From the emacs drop down menu the syntax checking is actually greyed out.

I know flycheck is working because syntax checking is working when I edit my .emacs file, so I think it's a problem with pylint. Any idea what I'm missing here?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem by installing the [exec-path-from-shell](http://melpa.milkbox.net/#/exec-path-from-shell) package from MELPA. I added the following code to my .emacs file.

```
(require 'exec-path-from-shell) ;; if not using the ELPA package
(exec-path-from-shell-initialize)
```

Comment: This is actually very good advice in general - helps in many cases when use  GUI version of emacs. I suggest you to mark your own answer as correct.

Comment: `exec-path-from-shell` link seems dead